# Nuget package : Copy some files only in asp.net projects

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, package, nuget

I have created a nuget package.

During the package restoration, I want to copy somes files of the package ("Content", "Scripts" folders) only if the project is a web project.

If the project is not web (example: a class library), just reference the .net libs without imports other files.

Possible ?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it myself, but I would probably start here:
[including msbuild props and targets in a package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#including-msbuild-props-and-targets-in-a-package)

Direct conditions for files to copy seems not to be possible at the moment: [Conditional assembly reference via NuGet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24804112/optional-or-conditional-folders-in-nuget-files-tag/25086330)